# Metapost and ConTeX

Tags: context, metapost

I am completely new to ConTeXt and have just started to experiment  with writing metapost directly within ConTeXt. My problem is that some of my existing metapost files call other metapost files which in turn call yet other metapost files.
How, do I get ConTeXt to recognise these other files?

Comment: Just use `\startMPinclusions[+] input mpfile; \stopMPincusions`.

Comment: @Aditya please do you mind writing an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Use `MPinclusions` for Metapost files that you want to include

```
\startMPinclusions[+] 
 input mpfile; 
\stopMPincusions
```

See [ConTeXt wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startMPinclusions) for more details.